# Pure CSS Popup (Use CSS to show/hide row when hover over previous row)

Tags: css

How can I collapse/show a table row using only CSS when I HOVER on the PREVIOUS row. Basically popup more information when I hover over a table row.

Comment: Where have you gotten stuck trying to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say call the "previous row" class `.previousRow`, and the row you want to change `.popUp`.

Lets assume that the `.popUp`'s display is `display:none;` and you can't see it currently.

Try using this in your CSS:

`.previousRow:hover + .popUp {display:block;}`

---

This selects the `popUp` class on the `previousRow` hover event and changes its display.

You could also interchange that display property to anything else you want to add on the previous row `:hover`.

Hope this helped!

Comment: This worked great and very simple.  Thank You so much!

Comment: I'm not allowed to upvote yet as I'm still new to stack.

Comment: You can still mark it as correct even though you are new, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this solve your question:

```css
.table1 tr {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  display: block;
}

.table1 tr:hover + tr  {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<table class='table1'>
    <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
 </table>
```

The selector `.table1 tr:hover + tr` will select the next row of the row being hovered.

Comment: This is pretty much what i was looking for only reversed. Thank you for this.